# Horizontal menu css with all time visible horizontal sub menu

Tags: html, css

I hope there is someone who can help me:

I would like a horizontal menu with horizontal sub-menues -  to be visible all time and submenus to be displayed horizontal, instead of vertical dropdown.
I have created a dropdown vertical - I can not change the submenus to bilve shown constantly horizontal

See [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PhuBQ/5/)

Comment: is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/PhuBQ/6/) the effect you want to achieve?

Comment: Almost, it is possible to get the submenu shown all the time?

Comment: Just a little question more, I hope you can help me with... When I click on one of the toplevel menu items that do not have sub-menus, it is possible to remove the sub menus in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PhuBQ/7/

the submenu is always visible and it's displayed horizontally.

Comment: Just a little question more, I hope you can help me with... When I click on one of the toplevel menu items that do not have sub-menus, it is possible to remove the sub menus in that case?